# How to make changes in a production mode project made with Laravel and Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I hosted my laravel-vue project after running the command 'npm run prod'. Now I need to make some changes after a while. The changes I am making to the blade files in view works just fine, but the changes I am making in js>components> {MyComponent}.vue file is not working. Before doing any changes I ran "npm run watch". So whenever I am making a  change in the components, "Laravel Build Successfull" is popping up, but no change reflecting in the browser. I also tried clearing my cache and all, but still all the same.